# print preview hides table border

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a regular table with a `1px border`. It looks fine and what not:[image]

but as soon as I go into the print preview, my borders become invisible:
[image]

When I print the page it comes out fine, it's only when I'm trying to save it to PDF that the lines don't show up
css:

```
.print_table {
    width: 900px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.print_table th{
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.print_table td{
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.print_table tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
}
.print_table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

EDIT: even tried `!important` on my borders, nothing.
Tried making the border 2px and it works but 2px is way too big

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole thing in a `@media all {}` rule. This applies the CSS to every kind of display, in this case, including printing as well as screens.

```
@media all {
    /* Your code here */
}
```

More on `@media` queries: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gbftsxsu/embedded/result/